# "warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size" Can't read process memory in C

Tags: c, winapi, readprocessmemory

I want to make a hack in C for a game I like, but when trying to read the memory from that game, the compiler gives me this warning:

> warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size

Which I think is causing problems when trying to read.

Here's the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>


int main(){
    int var = 0;
    long long addr = 0x7FFEB4BA0FC0;
    int pid = 1540;

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
    if(hProcess==NULL){
        printf("Failed to open Process");
        return 0;
    }
    BOOL rpmReturn = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)addr, &var, 1, NULL);
    if(rpmReturn==FALSE){
        printf("%llxFailed to read from memory", addr);
        return 0;
    }
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}
```

Full error:

```
Donut.c: In function 'main':
Donut.c:16:47: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
  BOOL rpmReturn = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)addr, &var, 1, NULL);
                                               ^
```

I'm using a `long long` on the address otherwise it would give me an "Overflow" warning which caused problems as well.

I searched everywhere and couldn't find a solution, so I hope someone can help me here.

I'm using gcc on Windows 64bit, BTW.

**Solution**: Thanks for helping yall! The solution was to install the 64 bit version. Have fun!

Comment: You could use type `uintptr_t` for `addr`, add `#include <inttypes.h>`, and change `"%llx..."` to `"%"PRIxPTR"..."`.

Comment: ..or why not use a pointer? Like `char *`?

Comment: Can you tell us, please, which platform you are compiling for? 32-bit or 64-bit? If it's targeting a 32-bit build then, whatever you do, the `0x7FFEB4BA0FC0` constant is invalid as a pointer, as it won't fit into 32-bits.

Comment: Whereas, if you're targeting a 64-bit build, then `long long` *should* be the same size as a pointer (64 bits), so I don't understand the warning.

Comment: @IanAbbott See my other comments. We need to know the platform and pointer size ...

Comment: Yea Im on windows and 64bit

Comment: But is your compiler set to build a 64-bit target? Please look at the settings.

Comment: Could you give us the result of `sizeof(LPCVOID)` and `sizeof(long long)`? As other suspect, you are likely to build for 32 bit. Just because windows is 64 bit, doesn't mean the compiler is set to produce 64 bit code.

Comment: On a side note, aside from the address, you are passing other wrong parameters to `ReadProcessMemory()`. You are asking it to read 1 byte into a multi-byte `int`. If you really mean to read 1 byte then use a `BYTE` instead of an `int` for the `lpBuffer` parameter. Otherwise, if you mean to read a full `int` then use `sizeof(int)` instead of 1 in the `nSize` parameter. Either way, `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` is way too many rights to ask for from `OpenProcess()` in this case. `ReadProcessMemory()` needs only `PROCESS_VM_READ`. Don't ask for more rights than you actually need.

Comment: Thanks for telling me I guess? It really doesnt seem to matter since that value just specifies how many bytes to read, not how large the buffer is.

Answer (score 4):

From the diagnostic given, it is clear that you are building your application as 32bit - as it is the only possible reason for the size of pointer to not be equal to size of `long long int`.

However, you can't use `int` directly instead of long integer, because the hexadecimal constant you have there would not fit into 32bit integer.

I have no idea where the magic address comes from, but you can't use it in 32bit program. Possible solutions would be to either compile program as 64bit, or change the address to one fitting into 32bit (again, this is unclear where it comes from in the first place).

Comment: Thanks, this was actually the issue. I installed the 64 bit version and it works perfectly now.